# JS cannot access object value from different function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

Can anyone axplain why the first thing works and the second dont?

```
function MyObj(val) {
    this.value = val;

    this.myFunc = function(selector) {
        $(selector).html("test: " + this.value);
    }
}

foo = new MyObj("tester");
foo.myFunc("#one"); //This works

func = foo.myFunc;
func("#two"); //This doesnt
```

How? and how can i make it work?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M8Qym/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function’s `this` in JavaScript isn’t fixed to anything; when you call

```
something.somefunc()
// or something['somefunc']()
```

`this` gets bound to `something`. When you call a function without an object, `this` gets bound to `undefined` (in strict mode) or the global object.

You can get around it by keeping a variable to hold the right `this`:

```
function MyObj(val) {
    var obj = this;

    this.value = val;

    this.myFunc = function(selector) {
        $(selector).html("test: " + obj.value);
    };
}
```

ECMAScript 5 offers a method on `Function.prototype` specifically to deal with this (and you should generally put `myFunc` on `MyObj.prototype`, too):

```
var func = foo.myFunc.bind(foo);
func("#two"); // Works now
```

Comment: LOL JavaScript will never stop trolling me, but Thanks :)

Comment: Using [apply() or call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) should also work when you pass foo: `func.call(foo,'#two');`

Comment: One minor detail, in strict mode `this` will be `undefined`. Not `null`.

Comment: @jaywalking101: Yikes, and on a recent answer, too! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `bind()` to assign the value of `this` to a function:

```
function MyObj(val) {
    this.value = val;

    this.myFunc = function(selector) {
        console.log(this); // <--- look your console output
        $(selector).html("test: "+this.value);
    }
}

foo = new MyObj("tester");
foo.myFunc("#one");

func = foo.myFunc;
func.bind(foo)("#two"); //  <---- here
```

or:

```
func = foo.myFunc.bind(foo);
func("#two");
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/M8Qym/1/

Comment: Although literally doing `func.bind(foo)("#two")` should really just be `func.call(foo, "#two")`.

Comment: the difference is that bind creates a new function, so he could use: `func = foo.myFunc.bind(foo);` and then just `func("#two");`

Comment: That’s why I said “literally” :)